# How to find the date range between two orders from the Order table with respect to subsequent Customer_Ids?

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

For eg- lets say we have a customer_id =1 and he has placed 3 orders in 2 years and his

1st Order_date = '1st Jan 2015'
2nd Order_date = '5th June 2015'
3rd Order_date = '2nd Feb 2016'.

This has to be calculated yearly from the date he has placed his first order.

Please let me know how to achieve this scenario in HiveQL.

Comment: What exactly has to be calculated?

Comment: I need to find the customer_id and subsequent order_date on yearly basis as stated in the example above.

Comment: Better provide input and required output data examples. This will save a lot of our time

Comment: Do you need to find 1st, second and third orders ? Or some date range? this is not clear

Comment: It is little bit difficult to show the output data. But I want a column which will be updated whenever the same customer makes the second purchase or transaction (True whenever there is repeat transaction). So essentially, this has to be done from the time he has made his first purchase in one year. Also this year is not the year from Jan to Dec. This has to be amended in such a way that the date difference between first order date and say 3rd order date falls in that very range.

Comment: Any leads here?

Comment: Are you going to provide examples of input and output datasets?

Comment: I somehow managed to write the code. Below is code attached, what I was looking for -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select ord_rnk_1.customer_id,ord_rnk_1.order_id as 1st_order, ord_rnk_2.order_id as 2nd_order, ord_rnk_1.order_date as 1st_order_date, ord_rnk_2.order_date as 2nd_order_date,
CASE 
WHEN nullif(ord_rnk_2.order_id,0)=0 THEN '1st purchase' 
WHEN datediff(ord_rnk_2.order_date,ord_rnk_1.order_date) <=365 THEN 'repeat purchase' 
ELSE '1st purchase' 
end as customer_type 
from
              (
                             select customer_id,order_id, order_date from 
                             (select  customer_id,order_id, order_date,row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by order_date asc) rank   from 
                               (select distinct customer_id, order_id, to_date(order_date,"dd/mm/yyyy") as order_date 
                                from table_t1
                                ) abc
                             ) order_rank where order_rank.rank=1
              ) ord_rnk_1
left join
              (
                             select customer_id,order_id, order_date from 
                             (select  customer_id,order_id, order_date,row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by order_date asc) rank
                              from 
                              (select distinct customer_id, order_id, to_date(order_date,"dd/mm/yyyy") as order_date
                               from table_t1
                             ) abc
                             ) order_rank where order_rank.rank=2
              ) ord_rnk_2
on ord_rnk_1.customer_id=ord_rnk_2.customer_id

Comment: Please let me know if this code can further be optimized